# Unwanted new line in TextView using HTML

Tags: android, textview, newline

I have a TextView that displays a string with some HTML for changing the format. I do it using this code:

```
text = "What symbol do 'all, only, <b>l</b>ike' have in common?";
title.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

The problem is that a new line character is inserted when it is not needed, i.e., I get this:

```
What symbol do 'all, only, 
like' 
have in common?
```

The break after "only," is right (there's no more room in that line), but the break after "like'" is not needed.

I've been doing tests and if in the string I change the bold tag from the "l" in "like" to the "l" in "only", i.e., I have this:

```
text = "What symbol do 'all, on<b>l</b>y, like' have in common?";
```

the text is correctly broken:

```
What symbol do 'all, only, 
like' have in common?
```

This baffles me, because it is exactly the same string except for that, and that should not have an effect in the line length.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

**Update:** My TextView in XML looks like this:

```
<TextView 
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ff000000" 
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:paddingLeft="10.0sp" 
    android:paddingRight="10.0sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Waiting for initialization..." />
```

Comment: I would suggest using `<strong>` instead of `<b>`

Comment: Same result. Thank you anyway.

Comment: My only guess is that the closing tag is triggering a break (which is why "on<b>l</b>y" looks like you expect since there is already a break there). Do you have a new line after "'all" if you try this "'a<b>l</b>l"?

Comment: No, I don't have a new line if I put the tag in "all". It works right in that situation, as in "only". Thank you anyway.

Comment: I have updated the question with the XML.

Comment: I don't get any new line feed! Which Android OS are you targetting?

Comment: Taget:8 Min:7. I don't get a new line feed with other strings. Maybe it depends on the size of the screen.

Comment: Ya I think your screen size is too small to fit and this is overflowing to the next screen, coz if you see the screenshot here on my phone API Version 7 http://imgur.com/QqxmX, it doesn't flow to the next screen and I have used `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

Comment: In my screen (the device is a Desire), the string needs two lines and works ok if the tag is in other place. In your screenshot, it looks like you haven't use textAppearanceLarge, so maybe that's the reason in doesn't overflow.

Comment: use text = "What&nbsp;symbol&nbsp;do&nbsp;'all,&nbsp;only,&nbsp;<b>l</b>ike'&nbsp;have&nbsp;in&nbsp;common?";
title.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

Comment: use `android:ellipsize="true"` and `android:singleLine="true"` property in textview

Comment: If use "&nbsp" now the second line breaks in the middle of "have", between "ha" and "ve".

Comment: If use "ellipsize" (with value "end", "true" is not valid) and "singleLine", just one line is shown with half of the sentence and ellipsis at the end, i.e., I get "What symbol do all, only, li...".

Comment: Its correcly line-broken in my emulator. (target 9, min 8)

Comment: It may depend on the resolution of your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You have android:layout_width="wrap_content" - which will wrap the text based on the available width in the layout. If you do not want it to wrap, specify android:layout_width="match_parent".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I want the text to wrap, but not in the middle of words.